# parse a txt file delimitered by pipe line by line

Tags: python, parsing

I have a text file delimitered by pipes. The problem is that  the format of this file is like below:

```
value 1|column name 1|value 2| column name 2|value 3|column name 3|...etc.
```

How to parse this kind of file? My goal is to transform it into a csv file in python. The value of each column could be empty, which means it could be like below:

```
value1|column name 1||column name 2|value 3|column name 3|...etc.
```

Comment: What do you want the output to be, have you tried writing it into python as a string and replacing the pipes with commas?

Comment: @Nhyi no I don't want to replace pipes with commas because the value could contain commas. I want to transform the column names into header in csv and the corresponding values under each column

Comment: Just read it as csv with pipe as delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this suffice?

```
import pandas as pd
path = r'C:\Path\To\Your\CSVFile.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(path, sep='|', header=None)
new_names = [i for sub in [('val_' + str(i), 'col_name_' + str(i)) for i in range(len(df.columns))] for i in sub]
df = df.rename({i[0]: i[1] for i in zip(df.columns, new_names)}, axis='columns')
df = df[df.columns.drop(list(df.filter(regex='col_name')))]
print(df)
```

Comment: Using Pandas for simply reading a file is severe overkill.